# AJAX: am I inserting data correctly?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I read many of the similar threads here to see what I'm doing wrong, but my AJAX call seems correct. What am I missing here? No alert is popping up, so I assume it's the JS side.

```
$("#SignupSubmit").click(function()
{
var fName = $("#txtSignFName").val();
var lName = $("#txtSignLName").val();
var email = $("#txtSignEmail").val();
var pw    = $("#txtPW").val();


if( fName == "" || lName == "" || email == "" || pw == "" )
{
    alert();
}

else 
{


    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "actionPages/signUp.php",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            fName:fName,
            lName:lName,
            email:email,
            pw:pw
        },
        success: function(response) {
            alert(response);
        }
    });
}
});
```

And the PHP (is this correct?):

```
<?php 

require "../connectionPages/localConnect.php";

$fName  = $_POST["fName"];
$lName  = $_POST["lName"];
$email  = $_POST["email"];
$pw     = $_POST["pw"];

if($fName == null || $lName == null || $email == null || $pw == null)
$message = "missing required data";
else
{

$SQL =  "INSERT INTO `customer/User` (custFName,
                            custLName,
                            custEmail,
                            custPassword)
VALUES ('$fName', '$lName','$email', '$pw')";

$mysqli->query($SQL);

if($mysqli->affected_rows > 0)
{
    $message = "Record successfully inserted <br><a href='..'>Back to Main Page</a>";

    $SQL = $mysqli->insert_id; /* $SQL = "SELECT max(custID) as ID FROM `customer/User`"; */
    $res = $mysqli->query($SQL) or trigger_error($mysqli->error."[$SQL]");

    json_encode($res);
}
else {
    $message = "Unable to insert record: " . $mysqli->error;
}
$mysqli->close();
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First phase update the below code in the data part.

```
data: {
            "fName":fName,
            "lName":lName,
            "email":email,
            "pw":pw
        },
```

And you are trying to get last inserted id. is it? if so use

```
$mysqli->insert_id;
```

instead of select query

Comment: Oh. It still doesn't work. i'm getting no alert. yes i'm trying to get the last ID

Comment: check your browser console and find the problem whether before sending data or after sending data. Also post your console message here to help further...

Comment: add `error: function (e) {           console.log(e);             }` after `success: function(response) {            alert(response);         }`

Comment: Ok I added that line. I still don't get an alert, but here's the console log: 


 "Object {readyState: 4, responseText: "Connected", status: 200, statusText: "OK"}"



That's without $mysqli->insert_ID, with it I get an error:

 "Connected. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual   that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax..for the following line:

    $res = $mysqli->query($SQL) or trigger_error($mysqli->error."[$SQL]");

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130569/discussion-between-naga-and-calisto).

Answer (score 0):

Do this in AJAX

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "actionPages/signUp.php",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        "fName":fName,
        "lName":lName,
        "email":email,
        "pw":pw
    },
    success: function(response) {
        var res=eval(response);
        alert(res.id);
    }
});
```

And in your PHP page. Do this:

```
if($mysqli->affected_rows > 0)
{
    $message = "Record successfully inserted <br><a href='..'>Back to Main Page</a>";

    $lastid = $mysqli->insert_id; /* $SQL = "SELECT max(custID) as ID FROM `customer/User`"; */
    // $res = $mysqli->query($SQL) or trigger_error($mysqli->error."[$SQL]");

    echo json_encode(array('id'=>$lastid));
}
```

I hope it helps